# split() in perl

Tags: perl

How to divide text into sentences. In my opinion, I should use split() and print them, but I donˇt now have.
I am just started learning Perl.

My text

*A block of text is a stack of line boxes.  In the case of 'left',
'right' and 'center', this property specifies how the inline-level
boxes within each line box align with respect to the line box's left
and right sides; alignment is not with respect to the viewport.  In
the case of 'justify', this property specifies that the inline-level
boxes are to be made flush with both sides of the line box if
possible, by expanding or contracting the contents of inline boxes,
else aligned as for the initial value. See also 'letter-spacing' and
'word-spacing'.*

Comment: Try writing a program that you think would work and then trying it out. If it doesn't work and you can't figure out why, post it in this question and you'll get much more useful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't actually homework, I would just use one of the [CPAN modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=sentence&mode=all) which handle this, say [Lingua::Sentence](http://search.cpan.org/~achimru/Lingua-Sentence-1.03/lib/Lingua/Sentence.pm) which seems to be under active development.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using `split` in combination with look-behind.

```
 perl -nlwe 'print for split /(?<=\S[.!?])\s+/' < data.txt
```

This works for your sample data.

What you want to do here is eliminate the space separating sentences. An end of sentence is defined as one of `.!?` preceded by a non-whitespace character. Tweak as desired.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$paragraph = "Text. Text";
@sentences = split(/\./, $paragraph);
print @sentences;
```

Comment: there is no output, how to fix it? Thnx

Comment: @user713744 try using print @sentences